# using If else if else statement getting error

Tags: javascript, if-statement

**I am newbie to javascript  I trying to code conditions for currency change based on shipping country but getting error for all conditions.**

Conditions

1. if the country is India and currency is Indian Rupees - Proceed to next page
2. if the country is India and currency is not India Rupees - alert as "Change currency as Indian Rupees"
3. if the country is not India and currency is India Rupees - alert as "Change currency as other than Indian Rupees"
4. if the country is not India and currency is not Indian Rupees - Proceed to next page

**Help me to correct the error.**

**Thanks in advance.**

```
<script>
function submitFunction() {
   var country=document.getElementById("location");
   var currency=document.getElementById("money");

   if (country =='India' && currency =='INR'){
      window.location.assign("thanks.html");
   } else if (country =='India' && currency !='INR') {
        alert("Change the currency as Indian Rupee");
   } else if (country !='India' && currency =='INR') {
        alert("Change the currency as other than Indian Rupee");
   } else {
        window.location.assign("thanks.html");
   }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="navMainSearch" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 

18px; margin-bottom: -15px;">
<form method="get" action="" name="currencies">
<select id="money" onchange="" name="currency" >
<option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
<option value="EUR">Euro</option>
<option value="GBP">British Pound Sterling</option>
<option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
<option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
<option selected="selected" value="INR">Indian 

Rupees</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="checkout" name="main_page">
<input type="hidden" name="fecaction">
</form>
</div>

<div id="checkoutShipto" class="floatingBox back">
<address class="checkoutAddress">
Raja 
<br>
423, Vinayagar Kovil Street
<br>
Chennai, 600027
<br>
TN,India<div id="location">India</div>
</address>
</div>

<div class="buttonRow forward">
<input type="submit" onclick="submitFunction()" title="Confirm Order " alt="Confirm Order" value="submit" act >
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the exact error you get?

Comment: In all conditions redirecting to next page

Comment: `currency` isn't what you think it is. Try logging it to the console and you'll see.

Comment: You're getting the element but not the content of the element i believe

`country=document.getElementById("money").innerHTML` might work

Comment: If used "document.getElementById("location").innerText" in all conditions redirecting next page

Comment: If used "document.getElementById("location").innerHTML" in all conditions diplaying alert as "Change the currency as Indian Rupee"

Answer (score 0):

Your currency is a select object, not a value.  To get the value of a select control you can use this code

```
var money = document.getElementById("money");
var currency = money.options[money.selectedIndex].value;
```

For country you should probably use

```
var country = document.getElementById("location").innerText;
```